# Optimal InfluxDB concept to read and write data

Tags: database, database-design, influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

I am using an Influx time-series database to archive tags from a controller. The data in the database is queried using cacheable queries and displayed on a dashboard. The tags are stored in the InfluxDB as follows:

[Build up in influx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4pZU.png)

There is only one bucket (mlog) and one measurement (mcc). Within this measurement, all tags are created as fields, in which the value is stored.

For example, a data record for a tag inside influx looks like the following.

[Data record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydGaF.png)

The data is queried using Flux. For example, a Flux query looks like the following:

```
import ""strings""
from(bucket:""{InfluxDL.InfluxBucket}"") 
     |> range(start:0, stop: now()) 
     |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == ""{InfluxDL.InfluxMeasurement}"" and strings.hasSuffix(v: r._field, suffix: ""{suffix}"") and r._time < time(v: ""{fromFormat}"") and r._value > 0.0) 
     |> last()
```

This has worked well so far, but I have now stored over 80 million archive records in the Influx database, causing the above Flux query to take approximately 3 minutes to execute.

I am using Influx version 2.6

I am using the PointData to write data to Influx. You can see the code below. nameGetter(x) is the name of the tag and valueGetter(x) is the value. timestampGetter(x) describes the timestamp of the tag. InfluxMeasurement is always defined as "mcc".

```
using (var writeApi = client.GetWriteApi())
{

    var saveData = data.Select(x => PointData.Measurement(InfluxMeasurement)
                                             .Field(nameGetter(x), valueGetter(x))
                                             .Timestamp(timestampGetter(x),   WritePrecision.Ns)).ToList();

    try
    {
        writeApi.WritePoints(saveData, InfluxBucket, InfluxOrg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       logger.Error("InfluxDL - WriteData()", ex);
    }
}
```

I've tried different flux queries but to no avail. I suspect that it is due to the way the data is stored in Influx. Which is why my question is as follows.

What should the structure look like so that data can be read and write efficiently and quickly, even if there are over 80 million data records in the database.

Does it make sense that a measurement is created for each tag?

Is there something I can change in the code for writing to the database? Are there more efficient ways or easier to configure?

Comment: `last()` should be fast even if you `start` from `0`, so I agree with your suspicion about the schema. Why are you _encoding_ tags into field name (using dot convention?) and not storing them as tags?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are still using the dot notation (which is quiet popular in OpenTSDB world) model. InfluxDB adopts the tag-field model where tags are indexed while field values are not.

The current model you are using is not leveraging InfluxDB's indexing capability and when you are query against the fields, you are hammering the systems by full table scan ("strings.hasSuffix(v: r._field, suffix: ""{suffix}"")").

Could you try parsing the fields into tag and field key? That is, for old field key "SRM.RBG01.ServiceData.General.NumberOfRelocations_1_1", convert it into

```
tag key: SRM
tag key: RBG01
tag key: ServiceData
tag key: General
tag key: NumberOfRelocations_1_1
```

Then you can query by a tag key and use [regex](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/regular-expressions/#use-a-regex-to-filter-by-tag-value) to filter the tag:

```
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == ""{InfluxDL.InfluxMeasurement}"" and r.tagKeyName =~ /{suffix}$/) and r._time < time(v: ""{fromFormat}"") and r._value > 0.0)
```

By the way, discarding dot notation model will help you to save a lot of storage space as tags are only saved once.